# Is it safe to resize a BTRFS partition that is part of a multi-device volume?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

I have a multi-device BTRFS volume and I would like to re-size one of the partitions. To be more precise:

My /home is spread across two separate BTRFS partitions. I shrunk down another partition to allow one of the BTRFS partitions to grow. One approach that I know of and have used to create a new BTRFS partition and add that to the pool.

A cleaner approach would be to grow the BTRFS partition, using the unallocated space I created. I would just pop in a GParted live CD and grow the partition itself, instead of creating a totally new partition on the unallocated space.

The question is: is this safe? Will the files that are already on the partition be found by the OS? Will the OS still recognize the partition as being part of the multi-device volume?

Comment: I took a risk and resized the BTRFS partition using the latest GParted live CD. The process took about 6 hours, but it was a success.When I rebooted, Linux detected the change in filesystem size and the additional free space was already alocated to the /home volume.

Answer (score 0):

This is the OP's comment that should be an answer:

> I took a risk and resized the BTRFS partition using the latest GParted live CD. The process took about 6 hours, but it was a success. When I rebooted, Linux detected the change in filesystem size and the additional free space was already allocated to the `/home` volume.

Note that BTRFS and GParted mentioned here refer to their versions from  *Mar 3 '13* or before. Current versions should maintain compatibility. Anyone feel free to update this community wiki.

Comment: "A particular device can be resized by specifying a devid" in the man page suggests that multiple device scenarios have been considered in the design of `btrfs filesystem resize`. Furthermore, if the device ID is omitted only the first device is resized, e.g. in a RAID 1 setup the second disk would have to be resized in a separate command.